# How can I center a tkinter rectangle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, centering, drawrectangle

I have everything I'd like my code to perform, but it is bugging me that the square is not centered. I've been searching the internet for hours...please help! I have tried using `anchor = "center"` and `.place()` but I just can't seem to get it right.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class draw():
     def __init__(self, can, start_x, start_y, size):
     self.can = can
     self.id = self.can.create_rectangle((start_x, start_y,start_x+size, start_y+size), fill="red")
     self.can.tag_bind(self.id, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.set_color)
     self.color_change = True

def set_color(self,event = None):
    self.color_change = not self.color_change
    colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet","pink","teal"]
    self.can.itemconfigure(self.id, fill = random.choice(colors))


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)
square = draw(canvas,1,1,90)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining a height and a width for the canvas and using `pack()` instead of `grid()` (like so)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class draw():
     def __init__(self, can, start_x, start_y, size):
       self.can = can
       self.id = self.can.create_rectangle((start_x, start_y,start_x+size, start_y+size), fill="red")
       self.can.tag_bind(self.id, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.set_color)
       self.color_change = True

     def set_color(self,event = None):
        self.color_change = not self.color_change
        colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet","pink","teal"]
        self.can.itemconfigure(self.id, fill = random.choice(colors))


WIDTH = 400 #change as needed
HEIGHT = 500 #change as needed
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()
square = draw(canvas,WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2,10)


root.mainloop()
```

You can center the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Your starting position is being set by your call to the draw method. You can have it automatically detect the correct center by calculating it from the canvas object.

```
size = 90
center_height = canvas.winfo_reqheight() / 2 - size / 2
center_width = canvas.winfo_reqwidth() / 2 - size / 2
square = draw(canvas, center_width, center_height, size)
```

You could also set start_x and start_y in the draw method if you'd prefer.